# Set the timeout for SSH connection establishment

Tags: linux, ssh

How to set the timeout for linux ssh connection establishment?
When a certain external connection comes in, eg: `ssh admin@192.168.0.100`, and it is in the stage of entering the password.
After a minute, the connection is dropped.
This requires modifying the ssh config file configuration on the client or server side?

Comment: The current state is that the connection is not established and the session is obtained, and it is only in the stage of entering the password.

Comment: I need to freely control its duration, where do I need to set this? And what is its default value (eg. centos7)

Answer (score 0):

i mis-read your question.

for connection timeout it's simple `ConnectTimeout` which specifics the timeout in seconds.

if you were wondering about SSH timeouts after you're already connected, the information below would be what you want.

you can do this on the client side in **~/.ssh/ssh_config** with `ServerAliveInterval` and `ServerAliveCountMax`

or on the server side in **/etc/ssh/sshd_config** with `ClientAliveInterval` and `ClientAliveCountMax`

the ***CountMax**, which normally defaults to *3*, sets the number of server alive messages sent without receiving any messages back.

the ***Interval**, which normally defaults to *0*, sets the timeout interval in seconds.

they work together, so if you set ***CountMax** to *20* and ***Interval** to *15* this it equates to 5 minutes.

Comment: Thx for helping to solve this problem